# Using Function in R Programming

Tags: r

I have a column named Interest with 10 values. I need to use function in R to multiply the values in the "Interest" column by 2 and to create a new column with the new multiplied values within the function.

Appreciate help, please.

I use the formula as :

```
col<-function(col){
  double<-col*2
  return(double)
}
df_col_double
```

Col = the name for the Interest column and double as the new column with the multipled values.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a function and probably your question has been answered, but here is the way using tidyverse package and using hp column from mtcars dataset as example:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% mutate(. , hp_2=hp*2)
```

hope this is what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using example data `mtcars`

```
col <- function(.data, col) {
  
  .data |> 
    dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across({{col}}, ~.x*2, .names = "double_{col}"))
}
col(mtcars,col = carb)
```